# R parse Pythonic String into valid R type

Tags: python, r, parsing, eval

I have some data set generated by Python using print string(variable).

I am wondering that is there an easy way so that I can evaluate the string into R variable.

Like, in python,

```
R.format.print(variable)
```

or in R

```
python.format.eval(string..)
```

Say my record looks like this:

```
('product1', 'manufacturer1')\t('arg1', num1, [list1])
```

What I am thinking right now is use

```
eval(parse(text=...))
```

combining with strsplit and strreplace to evaluate the text. 
Any one know any existing R package to friendly translate Python string into R variables?

Comment: Can you show the actual python data and the desired R data.  I don't really understand what you're asking for.  Generally, outputting a data structure to a string and trying to parse it back into a second language is going to be fraught with peril...

Comment: you should export/import using JSON format.